# "Connection must be valid and open"

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i have this error, i have been look at google and in another questions here and i cant find the answer to my problem, this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WebService1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Descripción breve de Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // Para permitir que se llame a este servicio web desde un script, usando ASP.NET AJAX, quite la marca de comentario de la línea siguiente. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hola a todos";
        }


        [WebMethod]
        public string ConectarBaseDatos()
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand())
                {

                    string connection = @"Data Source=localhost:3306; Database=sistemadatosatletasfecovol; 
                                User ID=movil; Password=***";
                    MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connection);


                    cm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cm.CommandText = "ingresarUsuario";
                    cm.Parameters.Add("_email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "asdasd@gmail.com";
                    cm.Parameters.Add("_password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "******";
                    cm.Connection = cn;
                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MySqlDataReader cr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                    cr.Read();
                    string id;
                    id = cr["idUsuario"].ToString();
                    return id;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

on the web Method "ConectarBaseDatos" and the problem appear when i execute `cm.ExecuteNonQuery()`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must open the connection before calling ExecuteNonQuery by using this code

```
 cn.Open();
```

Then, make sure you close the connection with this code at the end of the using block:

```
 cn.Close();
```

Comment: It's better to wrap connection with 'using' block (like the author did with MySqlCommand), since there is guarantee that the connection will be closed even when exception occurs. Then, cn.Close won't be needed.